# java alternative to running in separate processes

Tags: java, memory-leaks

In our Web application we are interfacing to third party library that is leaking memory. This causes our application to crash :(

One alternative is to run that third party in a separate operating system process.

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Upgrading third party library can help. I don't think running it as a separate process will really resolve the issue.

Comment: The best option is to fix the library so it doesn't have a memory leak.

Comment: I found this question "closed" now without any explanation why/how it violates the "guidelines". All I just looked for is for some standard approach, maybe some known library, that can be used to solve *real* problem.

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches:

1)  Run it as a separate OS process via Runtime.exec(), communicating via command-line, standard output or files;

or,

2) Run it in a separate JVM as a service, writing a facade around their library & communicating by TCP/ serialization.

I'd probably focus on option 2), but have code to restart the service automatically a la option 1) when the service stopped responding.

You can also try an updated version of their library, to see if it helps. Lastly, you could get the code & try and analyze/fix the leak. Not easy if it's C++, though.

Comment: +1; possibly the only two sensible suggestions, I do something similar using an approach based on (1).

Comment: I prefer separate OS process using Runtime.exec() function. +1